# List iterator outside range

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have a problem with the `STL list class`. I have a base class called Contact, and three derived classes, Friend, Colleague and Acquaintance. Each instance of the derived classes has certain fields which I modify in the fill*Class*Details() function. The problem is that when it reaches the push_back line, my program gives me an error saying `list insert iterator outside range`. What can that be from?

```
void Agenda::pushContact(string line, string temp)//function that adds a contact of type temp, containing the fields from line to the list
{       
    Contact *c;

    if(temp=="friend") //the contact to add is of type friend
    {
        c = new Friend();
        fillFriendDetails(c,line);//the details of Friend c will be filled
    }
    else if(temp=="colleague")
    {
        c = new Colleague();
        fillColleagueDetails(c,line);//the details of Colleague c will be filled
    }
    else if(temp=="acquaintance")
    {
        c = new Acquaintance();
        fillAcquaintanceDetails(c,line);//the details of Acquaintance c will be filled
    }
    contactList.push_back(c);
}
```

Also, the contactList is defined as `list <Contact*> contactList;`.

Edit: This is how the Contact class (+derived classes) are defined:

```
class Contact
{
public:
    string getFullName() {  string fullName;fullName.append(firstName); fullName.append(" ");fullName.append(lastName); return fullName;}
public:
    void setFullName(string newFirstName, string newLastName) { firstName = newFirstName; lastName = newLastName;}
public:
    string getFirstName() { return firstName;}
public:
    void setFirstName(string newFirstName) {firstName = newFirstName;}
public:
    string getLastName(){return lastName;}
public:
    void setLastName(string newLastName){lastName = newLastName;}
public:
    string getPhoneNo(){return phoneNo;}
public:
    void setPhoneNo(string newPhoneNo) {phoneNo = newPhoneNo;}
public:
    void setType(string newType){type=newType;}
public:
    string getType(){return type;}
private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string phoneNo;
    string type;

//SubClass setters and getters
public:
    virtual void setDateOfBirth(string birth) {}
    virtual string getDateOfBirth() {return 0;}
    virtual void setCity (string newCity) {}
    virtual string getCity() {return 0;}
    virtual void setFaculty (string newFaculty) {}
    virtual string getFaculty() {return 0;}
    virtual void setGroup (string newGroup) {}
    virtual string getGroup() {return 0;}
    virtual void setJob (string newJob) {}
    virtual string getJob () {return 0;}


};


class Friend : public Contact
{
public:
    void setDateOfBirth(string birth)   {dateOfBirth=birth;}
public:
    string getDateOfBirth() {return dateOfBirth;}
public:
    void setCity (string newCity){city=newCity;}
public:
    string getCity(){return city;}

private:
    string dateOfBirth;
    string city;    //current city of residence
};

class Colleague : public Contact
{
public:
    void setFaculty (string newFaculty){faculty = newFaculty;}
public:
    string getFaculty(){return faculty;}
public:
    void setGroup (string newGroup){group = newGroup;}
public:
    string getGroup(){return group;}


private:
    string faculty;
    string group;
};

class Acquaintance : public Contact
{
public:
    void setJob (string newJob){job=newJob;}
public:
    string getJob (){return job;}

private:
    string job;

};
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what is wrong in your program without looking at the problematic part of the code. What you have provided so far is far from ideal but doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Your problem is not due to this code. Try to create a minimal, complete program that exhibits this behavior. I suspect you will discover the problem as you whittle your real program down the a trivial sample. See http://sscce.org for more details.

Comment: P.s. This function may invoke undefined behavior if `temp` is none of the words listed. Do initialize `c` to either a valid value or the null pointer.

Comment: I agree with Rob, not intializing `c` could be part of the problem

Comment: Damn, I wish my id was Robbb right now.

Comment: In debug, the program does enter all those functions, fills the details according to the contact type. Also, I tried initializing c with NULL in the beginning, but it still doesn't work. I tried using a simplified program, but that seems to work.

Comment: @Johnsyweb : No, the problem appears in the very beginning of my program.

Comment: Also, you should investigate the "Abstract Factory Pattern". Just sayin'.

Comment: @Johnsyweb:I know, I will use it on the next project, but this one must be Pattern-free.

Comment: Is this project multi-threaded?

Comment: It's a bit off-topic to the question, and definitely not (at least not directly) part of the problem, but the design here could be a lot better. Ideally, you could have a map of string keys (matched to temp) and ContactFactory objects, each with a `create()` function that returns the proper class.

Comment: Heh, @Johnsyweb, you got there before me. :)

Comment: This problem is indeed very strange, since common sense says that the insert iterator for push_back (which is used internally in your STL implementation) should always point to the end of the list, and technically should always be valid. I guess we'll have to see more code. The best thing would be to have a fully compilable example that reproduces this issue.

Comment: I added the implementation of the Contact classes. The rest of my code is not really in use when the error occurs. As I mentioned before, the program crashes at the beginning.

Comment: Pushing onto a `std::list` makes a copy, I wonder if there is something in those classes that is failing on the copy and throwing the error?

Comment: @Robb To be honest, I thought of that, but don't really know how to test it.

Comment: @AdrianMar, I'd probably do it incrementally. Remove all the child class initilization and just see if you can add `Contact`s to the list. Then add in the child classes one at a time, seeing if one of the derived classes is the issue.  Basically isolating which class might be causing the problem and deducing from there.

Comment: I rechecked my code and it seems I applied a contactList.clear() on my list. That was the problem. But the question still exists. Why is using .clear() giving such an error?

Comment: OK, figured it out eventually. The problem with clear is that it deletes the pointers, but not the actual objects created with new. For those I (you) have to manually remove them. Thanks everybody!

Comment: @AdrianMar, bit of advice: You're storing dynamically allocated derived instances as a base pointer, and you don't have a virtual destructor in the base. Best case: You're leaking some memory. Worst case, you're leaking all of the memory. Suggestion, use `boost::ptr_list<T>` if you intend to store types like this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the list is being mismanaged at a different point in the code, because the error implies `end` is incorrect. Most likely either the list is deleted/out of scope or some incorrect `erase`s were performed on the list elements (say using invalid iterators).

Comment: The error occurs on the first use of the list. No other operations have been applied on it before this point (except the declaration itself).

Comment: You were dead on! I rechecked my code and it seems I applied a contactList.clear() on my list. That was the problem. But the question still exists. Why is using .clear() giving such an error?

Comment: OK, figured it out eventually. The problem with clear is that it deletes the pointers, but not the actual objects created with new. For those I (you) have to manually remove them. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianMar: I'm not sure how that explanation makes sense - clearing the list would leak memory, but that shouldn't corrupt the actual list object.  But if you're working I suppose there are worse mysteries to have in life.